# Getting replies of comments on posts in nested query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a query to get all the posts of your friends, the comments of each post and the replies of each comment:

```
MATCH (:User {email:{my_email}})-[:Friends]->(other_user:User)-[:Published]->(post:Post)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (commenters:User)-[:Published]->(comments:Comment)-[:Comments]->post
    OPTIONAL MATCH (repliers:User)-[:Published]->(reply:Reply)-[:Replied]->comments
    WITH post, other_user, comments, reply
    ORDER BY comments.timestamp DESC, reply.timestamp DESC
    RETURN post AS posts, other_user AS other, Collect(comments) AS comments, Collect(reply) as replies
    ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
```

I can get all the posts and the comments of the post but am **unable to get the replies of the comments**.

How do we execute such a query?

Comment: Do you have some representative sample data you can provide?

Comment: @DaveBennett i've figured out  the right query man. thanks for trying to help out

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to this query

Here is the right query:

```
  MATCH (:User {email:{my_email}})-[:Friends]->(User)-[:Published]->(post:Post)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (commenters:User)-[:Published]->(comment:Comment)-[:Commented]->post
  OPTIONAL MATCH (repliers:User)-[:Published]->(reply:Reply)-[:Replied]->comment
  WITH post, comment, reply
  ORDER BY reply.timestamp ASC
  WITH post, comment, Collect(reply) as replies
  ORDER BY comment.timestamp ASC
  WITH post, Collect({comment: comment, replies: replies}) as comments
  ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC
  RETURN Collect({post:post, comments:comments}) as posts
```

query explanation:

1. We get all our friends posts
2. Some `Post`s might not have comments yet so we use `OPTIONAL MATCH` on the `Comment`
3. Some `Comment`s might not have replies so we use `OPTIONAL MATCH` on the `Reply` as well
4. `ORDER BY` the replies in `ASC` order.. from oldest to newest
5. `Collect` all those replies
6. Then `ORDER BY` the comments in `ASC` order too.. from oldest to newest
7. Then `Collect` each individual `Comment` and their associated replies
8. `ORDER BY` the post in `DESC` order.. from newest to oldest
9. Then `Collect` each individual `Post` and it's associated comments

Comment: So, Comment and Reply are nodes? also, how will you include Likes on posts, will Likes be nodes or just relationships